# How to Remove a Singleton Data?

Tags: android, singleton

I have below code to set Singleton Data in my Application.It is saving data without problem.Now I need to refresh the data and set a new one everytime.I have tried adding a `clearInstance()` method setting the data to null.Then call the method before saving like `singleToneClass.clearInstance()` then call `singleToneClass.setData(mydata);` but it is not removing always showing the first saved data.How can I remove and refresh the data

```
public class singleToneClass {
String s;
private static final singleToneClass ourInstance = new singleToneClass();
public static singleToneClass getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}
private singleToneClass() {
}
public void setData(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
public String getData() {
    return s;
}

public void clearInstance() {
    this.s=null;
    s=null;

}
```

This is how I am trying to use it

```
 singleToneClass singleToneClass = com.techware.myapo.singleToneClass.getInstance();
 singleToneClass.clearInstance();
 singleToneClass.setData(mydata);
```

Comment: can you provide the code where you are using it?

Comment: I have updated my question with the using code

Comment: It's not clear where are you saving your data?

Comment: singleToneClass.setData(mydata);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using anti pattern singleton

```
    public class SingleToneClass{

    private static SingleToneClass singleToneClass;
    private String s;

    public static SingleToneClass getInstance(){
        if (singleToneClass == null) {
            singleToneClass = new SingleToneClass();
        }
        return singleToneClass;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param s can be null and no need to clearData method
     */
    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void clearData() {
        this.s = null;
    }

    public void printData() {
        System.out.print(this.s + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: tried but same result, it is keeping the first saved data

Comment: I called like below: 
SingleToneClass.getInstance().setS("abb");
        SingleToneClass.getInstance().printData();
        SingleToneClass.getInstance().clearData();
        SingleToneClass.getInstance().printData();
        SingleToneClass.getInstance().setS("nextdata");
        SingleToneClass.getInstance().printData();
and log printed:
abb
null
nextdata

Answer (score 0):

working solution,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SingleToneClass singleToneClass;
int countData=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    singleToneClass = SingleToneClass.getInstance();
}

public void setData(View view) {
    countData++;
    singleToneClass.clearInstance();
    singleToneClass.setData("Hello "+countData);

}
public void getData(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, singleToneClass.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="setData"
    android:text="Set" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="getData"
    android:text="Get" />
```

SingleToneClass.java

```
public class SingleToneClass {
String s;
private static final SingleToneClass ourInstance = new SingleToneClass();
public static SingleToneClass getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}
private SingleToneClass() {
}
public void setData(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
public String getData() {
    return s;
}

public void clearInstance() {
    this.s=null;        s=null;

}}
```